# Why doesn't this code work in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void)
{
    char a[5];
    int foo,i,num,result,bar;
    while (1)
    {
        cin>>a;
        int z = a[3]-'0';
        int y = a[1] - '0';
        int x = a[0] - '0';
        if ( x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0 )
            break;
        i = z;
        num = y*pow(10,i);
        i++;
        num = num+pow(10,i)*x;
        bar = num;
        while(bar%2!=0)
            bar--;
        cout<<num<<"\t"<<bar<<"\n";


    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have this code which accepts a string of the form xyez as input, where this string represents a number which is explained as follows: numbers first digit is x, its second digit is y, and then follow z zeros.

Now, all I am trying to do is outputtting the number and a value less than the formed number which is a power of 2. Also, I dont want to use log so I am using a simple while loop. But, on printing it for any input, such as 42e0, it outputs, 42 42. Why is it happening?

Comment: this is not quite a debugging service

Comment: I know, but it is just a simple code. I don't know why it is not decrementing the value. Please see it once.

Comment: I think the code behaves exactly as it should. I cannot see what else you expect it to do and why.

Comment: @chanchong `I know, but it is just a simple code` Which is more of a reason why *you* should be debugging it.

Comment: if it's power of two you can do `int val=1; while(val<target){ val<<1;} val>>1;` might not be the most efficient (and has obvious problems regarding edge-cases), just the first thing that comes to mind

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here, `bar` is `42`:

```
while(bar%2!=0)
    bar--;
```

Since the initial value is even, the loop body is never run and the variable is never decreased. Thus, both `bar` and `num` are 42.

I'm not sure what you pretend, but you can do:

```
bar--;
if (bar%2 != 0)
    bar--;
```

Next to every even number there is an odd number, no need to loop in the first place.

Comment: @chanchong: Yeah, anyway, the other people is right, you should try and learn a debugger. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: I have to find a number which is a power of 2 and is less than num, and I accidentally only put the modulus condition.

Comment: @chanchong: A power of 2?  Your question says it should be a multiple of 2.

Comment: @chanchong: Now that you have to find a power of two, my answer does not make any sense...